# User Login not Working after Migration 2.2 into 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, customer, magento2.3

I have Just Migration Magento 2.2 store in 2.3.1 Version but Customer User login not working after that. Give me below error.

> **The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.**

Comment: Did you mean by customer or admin?

Comment: Customer not working

Comment: Have you done a update or migration

Comment: Yes update magento 2.2 to 2.3.1..

Comment: Check Website ID for user